# How recreate the grey ellipse over a text to look like this in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, text

[image: logo]

How do I make a text look like this? 
This is a logo with a white text and a reflection of it, which I can do. I was wondering how to make the grey shadow that looks like an ellipse over the first half part of the text (which also covers the reflection below the text). I tried to cover the text with a grey ellipse after outlining it first. But I failed. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would use the Knockout Group Option. Here is my result:

[image]

*) Create white rectangle (background) and put it into the separate layer:

[image]

*) Create a new layer (e.g. text) and draw black rectangle:

[image]

*) Put your text over the black rectangle (the same layer):

[image]

*) Set Text Fill and Stroke Colors to None:

[image]

*) Go to Appearance Panel > Add New Fill:

[image]

*) Drag the new fill below the Characters:

[image]

*) Click on the Opacity link (below the new fill) and set Opacity to 0%:

[image]

*) Go back to your artboard, select the black rectangle and the text and group it (Object > Group)

*) Go to Appearance Panel > Click on the Opacity link > and check the Knockout Group option:

[image]

*) The Knockout has been made. Create a new layer (e.g. text bgnd) and start drawing the grey ellipse. Adjust its position and size:

[image]

*) Note that this method doesn’t expand your text – you can freely change the string content and Adobe Illustrator will recalculate your work fully automatically. Like this:

[image]

*) Of course, you can also easily change the background, text background and ellipse colors:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it.

Expand the black text. 
Draw your oval shape OVER where you want it to go. Colour it grey.
[image: draw over the top]

Select all of those items, then go to your pathfinder toolbar and click divide (first icon on the bottom row).

[image]

After clicking, use the direct selection tool to select the bottom bit of the oval then hit delete. This will leave you with what you want. Be careful to delete and holes in the words.

[image]

Hope this helps,
C

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer appling this effect by creating any grey oval/circular etc shape above the text and setting its transparency to 30% or any other sufficient value.
This preserve the text, keep the effect "live", thus you can adjust whenever you want in any way you want, i.e. changing the shape, its place, hue etc.

Comment: I already tried this, it seems to be working, although I don't know what to do with the extra ellipse that goes beyond the text...